# PHP extension sodium with IIS

Tags: php, iis, sodium

We cannot get the PHP library working with IIS and cannot find instructions on how to get it installed on IIS.

There are pointers that the library dll must also be copied to the apahce directory for Apache but nothing for IIS.  We are using php v.8 and IIS.

```
<?php
var_dump(extension_loaded('sodium'));
?>
```

always returns false.

We have added the extension to php.ini, added the path of the extension to the windows PATH environmental variable.  We have also downloaded the sodium library from Windows and tried the dynamic library.

Looking at Apache instructions, it seems that we need to install the library into IIS but don't know how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: About how to configure PHP on IIS you can refer to this link: [Install and Configure PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php).